# What is the main character buying in the open scene at the market "The hundred foot journey"?

Tags: the-hundred-foot-journey

It seems to be some dark spiky fruit with thorns and jelly-like substance inside. Might look strange but seems to have a great fragrance.

While this fact might be trivia, I did some research and could not find a reference, including Wikipedia article about this movie.

Comment: This sounds like trivia. If it's not, can you explain how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not fruit - the basket that Hasan and his mother chase though the market and ultimately buy from the vendor is actually full of sea urchins. I've only ever come across dead and hollow urchin shells myself, but apparently they are quite fleshy and tasty.

https://abcnews.go.com/amp/Lifestyle/wireStory/spiny-delicious-sea-urchins-shine-documentary-70492501